# How to build multivariate ranking system?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, ranking

I have data of various sellers on ecommerce platform. I am trying to compute seller ranking score based on various features, such as

1] Order fulfillment rates [numeric]

2] Order cancel rate [numeric]

3] User rating [1-5] { 1-2 : Worst, 3: Average , 5: Good} [categorical]

4] Time taken to confirm the order. (shorter the time taken better is the seller) [numeric]

My first instinct was to normalize all the features, then multiply parameters/feature by some weight . Add them together for each seller score. Finally, find relative ranking of sellers based on this score.

My Seller score equation looks like

Seller score = w1* Order fulfillment rates - w2*Order cancel rate + w3 * User rating + w4 * Time taken to confirm order

where, w1,w2,w3,w4 are weights.

My question is three fold

Are there better algorithms/approaches to solve this problem? i.e I linearly added the various features, I want to know better approach to build the ranking system?

How to come with the values for the weights?

Apart from using above features, few more that I can think of are ratio of positive to negative reviews, rate of damaged goods etc. How will these fit into my Score equation?

How to incorporate numeric and categorical variables in finding seller ranking score? (I have few categorical variables)

Is there an accepted way to weight multivariate systems like this ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following approach:

First of all, keep in a matrix all features that you have available, whether you consider them useful or not.

(Hint: categorical variables are converted to numerical by simple encoding. Thus you can easily incorporate them (in the exact way you encoded user rating))

Then, you have to apply a dimensionality reduction algorithm, such as Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), in order to keep the most significant variables. Applying SVD may surprise you as to which features may be significant and which aren't.

After applying SVD, choosing the right weights for the n-most important features you decided to keep, is really up to you because it is purely qualitative and domain-dependent (as far as which features are more important).

The only way you could possibly calculate weights in a formalistic way is if the features were directly connected to something, e.g., revenue. Since this very rarely occurs, I suggest manually defining the weights; but for the sake of normalization, set:

w1 + w2 + ... + wn = 1

That is, split the "total importance" among the features you selected in a manner that sums to 1.